# Error while generating AWS session token using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sts, aws-credentials

I am trying to use session token using AWS sts_client

```
AWSSecurityTokenService sts_client =  AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                                             .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://sts.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com", "ap-southeast-2"))
                                             .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2).build();
```

getting below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one of Region or EndpointConfiguration may be set.
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:450) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.234.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.234.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.234.jar:na]
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Amazon STS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html) for **temporary credentials**. You get those credentials, including token, using for example [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html).

Answer (score 0):

### This below code working for me:

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("----ACESSKEY----",
"---SECRET ACCESS KEY");

```
    AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);

    AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
            .withRoleArn("--------RoleArn----------")
            .withDurationSeconds(3600).withRoleSessionName("TEST");

    AWSSecurityTokenService securityTokenService = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(credentialsProvider).build();

    AssumeRoleResult result = securityTokenService.assumeRole(assumeRequest);
```